# Create a salesforce user entry in iOS using REST API?

Tags: ios, rest, salesforce

I was wondering if anyone could point out how to create new user / lead entries in salesforce?
I've tried looking at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't do it out of the box with the Rest API, but, you can make your custom webservices with **Apex REST** (check out some code example: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm )

I found myself doing that for things I could not achieve using the regular Rest API, in your case, you could do just about the same thing.

Comment: You can create a user via the regular out of the box REST API, you create an SObject called User.

Comment: superfell, I was wondering if you could give an example of this? Thanks!